# Python - split and enumerate a string, check if 2 words are within a certain distance within string

Tags: python, string, parsing, text, enumeration

I'm working on a g program that will check for certain patterns in a research study's title to determine if the title may be relevant. Typically, it will be relevant if the words "access" and "care" are within 4 words of each other.  There could be phrases like "access to care," "patient access," or "access to diabetes care."

Right now, I've enumerated and split each string and I've filtered out rows that have "access" and "care" in them, along with a number, but I've struggling to create a binary "yes/no" variable for if they are within 4 words of each other. For example:

string = "Ensuring access to care is important." 
relevant = 'yes'

string = "Ensuring access to baseball tickets is important, but honestly I don't really care." 
relevant = 'no'

Any ideas for how to go about this would be appreciated.  Here's what I have thus far:

```
  sentence = 'A priority area for this company is access to medical care 
  and how we address it.'
  sentence = sentence.lower()
  sentence = sentence.split()
  for i, j in enumerate(sentence):

      if 'access' in j:
          x = 'yes'
      else:
          x = 'no'

      if 'care' in j:
          y = 'yes'
      else:
          y = 'no'   

      if x == 'yes' or y == 'yes':
          print(i, j, x, y)
```

Comment: Can the words repeat?

Comment: Sounds like you should be counting words. Store the value of `i` when you encounter one of them, then when you encounter the next one, `i - i_first` will tell you how many words separate the two instances. If the result is less than your threshold (currently 4), then return `True`, else `False`. If you want to get more sophisticated (and likely faster), you could use regular expressions for this as well.

Comment: The words can repeat (and likely will).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily do it avoiding all these loops:

```py
sentence = 'A priority area for this company is access to medical care and how we address it.'
sentence = sentence.lower().split()

### if both in list
if 'access' in sentence and 'care' in sentence :
    ### take indexes
    access_position = sentence.index('access')
    care_position = sentence.index('care')
    ### check the distance between indexes
    if abs( access_position - care_position ) < 4  :
        print("found access and care in less than 4 words")

### result:
found access and care in less than 4 words
```

Comment: This should probably use the absolute value of the subtraction in case "care" comes first in the title.

Comment: `abs( access_position - care_position) < 4`

Comment: If a word occurs multiple times, `sentence.index(word)` will only return the index of the first (leftmost) occurrence. Consider the sentence "Access to tickets and access to care". It's relevant, but the above code will not detect it.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the index so you can check it with using indexs.
Modify your code to :

```
sentence = 'A priority area for this company is access to medical care and how we address it.'

sentence = sentence.lower()
sentence = sentence.split()
access_index = 0
care_index = 0
for i, j in enumerate(sentence):

      if 'access' in j:
          access_index= i


      if 'care' in j:
          care_index = i

if access_index - care_index < 4:
          print ("Less than 4 words")
else:
          print ("More than 4 words")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
access = sentence.index("access")
care = sentence.index("care")

if abs(care - access) <= 4:
    print("Less than or equal to 4")
else:
    print("More than 4")
```

Of course, modify the above code to suit your particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence has more than one occurrence of "care" or "access", all the answers so far will only consider one of them, which will sometimes fail to detect a match. Instead, you need to consider all occurrences of each word:

```
sentence = "Access to tickets and access to care"
sentence = sentence.lower().split()

access_positions = [i for (i, word) in enumerate(sentence) if word == 'access']
care_positions = [i for (i, word) in enumerate(sentence) if word == 'care']

sentence_is_relevant = any(
    abs(access_i - care_i) <= 4
    for access_i in access_positions
    for care_i in care_positions
)
print("sentence_is_relevant =", sentence_is_relevant)
```